# Read and parse text file onto structure json file - return unwanted key and null/dict in the json file

Tags: python, json, text

couldn't find similar issue here. I'm getting null and unwanted dict after convert a file onto json structure. The script and file below.

From the raw1.txt file, 1st remove specific line/string and write to new file as clean.txt. 
Second read clean.txt file and convert them to structure json format.

Able to run it without error return json file (myjson.json) but some how also some part of json data return unwanted key/value/dict like below..

```
{
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      null
    ]
  }
```

..it could be found anywhere in the json file.... the problem is due to multiple empty line that still exist after remove require lines.

Please find below

Raw file (raw1.txt)

```
         OSPF Process 1 with Router ID 1.4.0.1
                         Area: 0.0.0.10
                 Link State Database


  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.4.0.1
  Adv rtr   : 1.4.0.1
  Ls age    : 996
  Len       : 48
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 8000002f
  chksum    : 0xe7f5
  Link count: 2
   * Link ID: 1.16.9.9
     Data   : 10.1.155.2
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 100
   * Link ID: 10.1.155.20
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 100
     Priority : Low

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.16.9.9
  Adv rtr   : 1.16.9.9
  Ls age    : 392
  Len       : 48
  Options   :  ABR  E
  seq#      : 8000001e
  chksum    : 0x3116
  Link count: 2
   * Link ID: 1.4.0.1
     Data   : 10.242.177.21
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 1
   * Link ID: 10.1.155.20
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low
                         Area: 0.0.0.13
                 Link State Database


  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.4.0.2
  Adv rtr   : 1.4.0.2
  Ls age    : 1194
  Len       : 96
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 8001cf7b
  chksum    : 0xbfae
  Link count: 6
   * Link ID: 1.4.0.2
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 0
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 1.4.0.1
     Data   : 10.0.0.2
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.0.0.0
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Low
   * Link ID: 10.40.8.0
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 100
     Priority : Low
   * Link ID: 19.23.23.15
     Data   : 10.40.10.130
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 1.4.10.200
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Low


  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 100.100.0.10
  Adv rtr   : 100.100.0.10
  Ls age    : 171
  Len       : 84
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 8001a292
  chksum    : 0x5fa2
  Link count: 5
   * Link ID: 100.100.0.10
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 12
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.1
     Data   : 10.10.10.18
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.10.10.17
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 19.23.23.15
     Data   : 10.10.30.30
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.90.25.30
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 10.10.0.1
  Adv rtr   : 10.10.0.1
  Ls age    : 191
  Len       : 96
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 80013bcf
  chksum    : 0x9871
  Link count: 6
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.1
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 12
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 15.51.51.14
     Data   : 10.10.0.130
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.129
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 100.100.0.10
     Data   : 10.10.10.17
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.10.10.18
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 16.16.16.0
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Low

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 15.51.51.14
  Adv rtr   : 15.51.51.14
  Ls age    : 2487
  Len       : 60
  Options   :  ASBR  ABR  E
  seq#      : 8000003c
  chksum    : 0x1714
  Link count: 3
   * Link ID: 10.242.95.12
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.1
     Data   : 10.10.0.129
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 1
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.128
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low
```

json file (myjson.json)

```
[
  {
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "996",
    "seq#": "8000002f",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.16.9.9",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "100",
        "Data": "10.1.155.2"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "48",
    "Ls id": "1.4.0.1",
    "chksum": "0xe7f5",
    "Adv rtr": "1.4.0.1",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "2"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "392",
    "seq#": "8000001e",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.4.0.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "10.242.177.21"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "48",
    "Ls id": "1.16.9.9",
    "chksum": "0x3116",
    "Adv rtr": "1.16.9.9",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ABR  E",
    "Link count": "2"
  },
  {
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "1194",
    "seq#": "8001cf7b",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.4.0.2",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "0",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.4.0.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.0.0.2"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.0.0.0",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.252",
        "Priority": "Low"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.40.8.0",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "100",
        "Data": "255.255.255.252",
        "Priority": "Low"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "19.23.23.15",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.40.10.130"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "96",
    "Ls id": "1.4.0.2",
    "chksum": "0xbfae",
    "Adv rtr": "1.4.0.2",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "6"
  },
  {
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "171",
    "seq#": "8001a292",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "100.100.0.10",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "12",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.0.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.10.10.18"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.10.17",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "19.23.23.15",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.10.30.30"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "84",
    "Ls id": "100.100.0.10",
    "chksum": "0x5fa2",
    "Adv rtr": "100.100.0.10",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "5"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "191",
    "seq#": "80013bcf",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.0.1",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "12",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "15.51.51.14",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.10.0.130"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.0.129",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "100.100.0.10",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.10.10.17"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.10.18",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "96",
    "Ls id": "10.10.0.1",
    "chksum": "0x9871",
    "Adv rtr": "10.10.0.1",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "6"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "2487",
    "seq#": "8000003c",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "10.242.95.12",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "255.255.255.252",
        "Priority": "Low"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.0.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "10.10.0.129"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "60",
    "Ls id": "15.51.51.14",
    "chksum": "0x1714",
    "Adv rtr": "15.51.51.14",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  ABR  E",
    "Link count": "3"
  },
  {
    "items": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      null
    ]
  }
]
```

Script

```
# To remove specific line/string
filename = 'raw1.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
with open('clean.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in lines:
        if not re.match(r"\s+(Area|OSPF|Link State)", line):
            fout.write(line)

#To return clean file onto json structure
results = []
group = {}
group['items'] = []
subgroup = None

with open('clean.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip():
            results.append(group)
            group = {}
            group['items'] = []
            subgroup = None
        elif not line.startswith('   '):
            key, val = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            val = val.strip()
            group[key] = val
        else:
            if '*' in line:
                if subgroup:
                    group['items'].append(subgroup)
                subgroup = {}
            key, val = line.split(':')
            key = key.replace('*', '').strip()
            val = val.strip()
            subgroup[key] = val

group['items'].append(subgroup)
results.append(group)
print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))

with open('myjson.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(results, json_file)
```

I'm expecting clean text and json like below

```
  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.4.0.1
  Adv rtr   : 1.4.0.1
  Ls age    : 996
  Len       : 48
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 8000002f
  chksum    : 0xe7f5
  Link count: 2
   * Link ID: 1.16.9.9
     Data   : 10.1.155.2
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 100
   * Link ID: 10.1.155.20
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 100
     Priority : Low

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.16.9.9
  Adv rtr   : 1.16.9.9
  Ls age    : 392
  Len       : 48
  Options   :  ABR  E
  seq#      : 8000001e
  chksum    : 0x3116
  Link count: 2
   * Link ID: 1.4.0.1
     Data   : 10.242.177.21
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 1
   * Link ID: 10.1.155.20
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.4.0.2
  Adv rtr   : 1.4.0.2
  Ls age    : 1194
  Len       : 96
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 8001cf7b
  chksum    : 0xbfae
  Link count: 6
   * Link ID: 1.4.0.2
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 0
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 1.4.0.1
     Data   : 10.0.0.2
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.0.0.0
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Low
   * Link ID: 10.40.8.0
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 100
     Priority : Low
   * Link ID: 19.23.23.15
     Data   : 10.40.10.130
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 1.4.10.200
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Low

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 100.100.0.10
  Adv rtr   : 100.100.0.10
  Ls age    : 171
  Len       : 84
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 8001a292
  chksum    : 0x5fa2
  Link count: 5
   * Link ID: 100.100.0.10
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 12
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.1
     Data   : 10.10.10.18
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.10.10.17
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 19.23.23.15
     Data   : 10.10.30.30
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.90.25.30
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 10.10.0.1
  Adv rtr   : 10.10.0.1
  Ls age    : 191
  Len       : 96
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 80013bcf
  chksum    : 0x9871
  Link count: 6
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.1
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 12
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 15.51.51.14
     Data   : 10.10.0.130
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.129
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 100.100.0.10
     Data   : 10.10.10.17
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.10.10.18
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 16.16.16.0
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Low

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 15.51.51.14
  Adv rtr   : 15.51.51.14
  Ls age    : 2487
  Len       : 60
  Options   :  ASBR  ABR  E
  seq#      : 8000003c
  chksum    : 0x1714
  Link count: 3
   * Link ID: 10.242.95.12
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.1
     Data   : 10.10.0.129
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 1
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.128
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low
```

```
[
  {
    "Ls age": "996",
    "seq#": "8000002f",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.16.9.9",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "100",
        "Data": "10.1.155.2"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "48",
    "Ls id": "1.4.0.1",
    "chksum": "0xe7f5",
    "Adv rtr": "1.4.0.1",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "2"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "392",
    "seq#": "8000001e",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.4.0.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "10.242.177.21"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "48",
    "Ls id": "1.16.9.9",
    "chksum": "0x3116",
    "Adv rtr": "1.16.9.9",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ABR  E",
    "Link count": "2"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "1194",
    "seq#": "8001cf7b",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.4.0.2",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "0",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.4.0.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.0.0.2"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.0.0.0",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.252",
        "Priority": "Low"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.40.8.0",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "100",
        "Data": "255.255.255.252",
        "Priority": "Low"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "19.23.23.15",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.40.10.130"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "96",
    "Ls id": "1.4.0.2",
    "chksum": "0xbfae",
    "Adv rtr": "1.4.0.2",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "6"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "171",
    "seq#": "8001a292",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "100.100.0.10",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "12",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.0.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.10.10.18"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.10.17",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "19.23.23.15",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.10.30.30"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "84",
    "Ls id": "100.100.0.10",
    "chksum": "0x5fa2",
    "Adv rtr": "100.100.0.10",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "5"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "191",
    "seq#": "80013bcf",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.0.1",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "12",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "15.51.51.14",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.10.0.130"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.0.129",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "100.100.0.10",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "10.10.10.17"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.10.18",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "96",
    "Ls id": "10.10.0.1",
    "chksum": "0x9871",
    "Adv rtr": "10.10.0.1",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "6"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "2487",
    "seq#": "8000003c",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "10.242.95.12",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "255.255.255.252",
        "Priority": "Low"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "10.10.0.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "10.10.0.129"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "60",
    "Ls id": "15.51.51.14",
    "chksum": "0x1714",
    "Adv rtr": "15.51.51.14",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  ABR  E",
    "Link count": "3"
  },
]
```

I really appreciate someone to help and advise further. thank you

Comment: you may have problem because there are lines like `OSPF Process 1 with Router ID 1.4.0.1` or `Area: 0.0.0.13` which are not expected by code. Code treats them as configuration and it creates dictionary but it can't find elements in these parts so it creates dictionary only with `items`. You would have to recognize these lines and skip them. They have more spaces at the beginning then other lines so it could be used to recogize these lines.

Comment: Hi..sir..those lines have been remove earlier and clean.txt file in the 1st part of the script. clean.txt is already clean with no lines assc with OPSF .... link state... and Area ...

Comment: I think there are still two empty lines between every "Area" and many empty lines at the beginning but code expects only one empty line between groups and zero empty lines at the beginning. Code uses empty line to recognize end of group and start new group.

Comment: Hi sir...yup....the 1st part of the script only remove those require lines (Area..OSPF...Link State...)...but not empty line after it... thus.. more than single empty line will be remain in the file and that create the problem above...

Comment: dictionary `{"items": []}` has only one key - "items". Other dictionares have more keys so you can check it before you add to result: `if len(group) > 1: results.append(group)`